# Create JWT security for two entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jwt, entity

I've got two entities as two type of account in my spring app:
Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "customer_id",updatable = false)
    private String customerId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Nickname may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Nickname '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "nickname",updatable = false)
    private String nickname;
    @NotBlank(message = "City may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "City '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @NotBlank(message = "Phone Number may not be blank")
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{9})")
    @Column(name = "phone_number",updatable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email may not be blank")
    @Email
    @Column(name = "mail",updatable = false)
    private String mail;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 5 , max = 30, message = "Password '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

// getters setters
}
```

and Specialist:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "specialist")
public class Specialist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "specialist_id",updatable = false)
    private String specialistId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Name may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Name '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "name",updatable = false)
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "Surname may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Name '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "surname",updatable = false)
    private String surname;
    @NotNull(message = "Province may not be blank")
    @Column(name = "province")
    private Province province;
    @NotBlank(message = "City may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "City '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @NotBlank(message = "Profession may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "Profession '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "profession")
    private String profession;
    @NotBlank(message = "Phone Number may not be blank")
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{9})")
    @Column(name = "phone_number",updatable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email may not be blank")
    @Email
    @Column(name = "mail",updatable = false)
    private String mail;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 5 , max = 30, message = "Password '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "rate")
    private HashMap<String,Double> rateStars;
    @Range(min = 0 , max = 5)
    @Column(name = "average_rate")
    private Double averageRate;
//getters setters
}
```

As you can see this entities have got differently required fields.
Now I want to create JWT where specialist and customer have got other access to endpoints.
For example specialist has got other header than customer in front end.
And now i ask question to You, how connect two differently entities to JWT security? Because all of tutorials/posts in internet concerns JWT only to one User entity and then separate role.

I tried to solve this but I stand with this how to supersede User entity and change this to my Specialist and Customer entities:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        return user;
    }

    @Transactional
    public User loadUserById(Long id){
        User user = userRepository.getById(id);
        if(user == null) new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        return user;
    }
```

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return User.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) object;

        if(user.getPassword().length() < 6){
            errors.rejectValue("password","Length","Password must be at least 6 characters");
        }

        if(!user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword())){
            errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword","Match","Passwords must match");
        }

    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        InvalidLoginResponse loginResponse = new InvalidLoginResponse();
        String jsonLoginResponse = new Gson().toJson(loginResponse);

        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(jsonLoginResponse);

    }
}
```

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try{

            String jwt = getJWTFromRequest(httpServletRequest);

            if(StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)){
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);
                User userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,null, Collections.emptyList()
                );

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String getJWTFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if(StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)){
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;

    }


}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME);

        String userId = Long.toString(user.getId());

        Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("id",(Long.toString(user.getId())));
        claims.put("username", user.getUsername());
        claims.put("fullName", user.getFullName());

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userId)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();

    }


    public boolean validateToken(String token) {

        try{
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        }catch (SignatureException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Signature");
        }catch (MalformedJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Token");
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Expired JWT token");
        }catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Unsupported JWT token");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            System.out.println("JWT claims string is empty");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Long getUserIdFromJWT(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        String id = (String)claims.get("id");

        return Long.parseLong(id);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unAuthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(){
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unAuthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() //To enable H2 db
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URLS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(H2_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all of tutorials/posts in internet concerns JWT only to one User entity and then separate role.

You may store users in two tables but they are users of two different roles- `Customer` and `Specialist`

> how connect two differently entities to JWT security?

```java
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      /**
        * logic to check if this username belongs to Customer/Specialist 
        * based on that create a new Authority - ROLE_CUSTOMER or ROLE_SPECIALIST
        */
}
```

> specialist has got other header than customer in front end.

These are Menu if I am not wrong. Based on Authority that you passed using above method, you can show Menu.